# How to not display in dom when using condition with ngFor

Tags: html, angular

I am using `ngFor` to display some data based on this array like below.

I want to skip the categories element and not display any element in dom for this element of array.

I have tried with `ngIf` but I still have displayed an empty div from `ngFor` `class="categories-filter"`.

How can I skip the categories item?

```
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
          <div *ngIf="filter !== 'Filter2'">
            <span> {{ someVar }}</span>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="filter === 'Filter1'">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
          <li class="col-3">
            <span> Rate </span>
              <nz-slider nzRange ></nz-slider>
          </li>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a `ng-container` to skip outer div (which is the empty div you get):

```
<div class="row">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let filter of filters">
   <div  class="col-3 categories-filter" *ngIf="filter !== 'CATEGORIES' || filter === 'RATINGS'">
      <div *ngIf="filter !== 'CATEGORIES'" class="content-filter">
        <span class="categories-title"> {{ someVar }}</span>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="filter === 'RATINGS'" class="content-filter">
        <li role="menuitem pt-0 mt-0">
          <i-feather name="star" *ngFor="let s of ratingStars" class="star fill-star"></i-feather> and above
        </li>
      </div>
   </div>
 </ng-container>
 <div class="col-3">
    <li role="menuitem" class="col-3">
      <span class="categories-title">Price range</span>
          <nz-slider nzRange ></nz-slider>
    </li>
 </div>

 </div>
```

what is `ng-container`:

*The ng-container is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.*

Here is the documentation: [Structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directives)